# External Activity not found Exception

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

I have used this library project in my app [Scan document library]
I have also included OpenCv android SDk in my app.
The app is getting compiled fine. After running, onclick of scan button ,
The ScanActivity is not getting recognised. It gives following error:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class {com.myapptest/com.scanlibrary.ScanActivity}

Comment: Have you declared that in manifest..

Comment: @Shivam Oberoi, It is from external library, do I need to add it in my manifest If I have included it in my gradle file?

Comment: My settings.gradle:i
nclude ':app', ':scanlibrary'
include ':openCVLibrary340'
My app gradle:
 compile project(':openCVLibrary340')
    compile project(':scanlibrary')

Comment: Are you using it somewhere com.myapptest/com.scanlibrary.ScanActivity?

Comment: com.scanlibrary.ScanActivity is from the impoerted library  and I am using it in myapptest